# How to add a modal ajax popup in myaccount order view page?

Tags: ajax, magento2

I am working on front-end order history detail view page. I need to display a dynamic popup preferably modal popup with Ajax on click on a link.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself. In `view/.../order/item.phtml` I added the below code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myinfo-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <div class="my-container">your text here
    </div>
</div>
</div>
   <script>
require(['jQueryNoConflict'], function(jQuery){
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {                    
                jQuery(document).on('show.bs.modal','#myinfo-modal', function (e) {
    jQuery.ajax({
                     url:  '<your url here>',
                     type: 'POST',
                     data: {id: 3},
                     success: function(response){
                        jQuery('.my-container').html(response.success);
                      
                     },
                     error: function(){
                       jQuery('.my-container').html("<your error msg here>");
                      
                     }  
                  });  
                });
});  });
```

In your order/items/renderer/default.phtml add below code

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my-modal" data-id="2">View Modal Popup</a>
```